# How to enable logging output in adal-angular when minified

Tags: angularjs, adal

We run into frequent auth issues using adal angular.  I have found it helpful to push the logs out to the console when debugging by adding this to our config file:

```
    Logging = {
        level: 3,
        log: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to pipe this to our telemetry store (Azure App Insights) so that we can pull data proactively.  Our files are minified, however, and this breaks minification with:

```
(Bundler & Minifier) Strict-mode does not allow assignment to undefined variables: Logging
```

This makes sense as I am not defining Logging, just setting a value on it.

Short of downloading adal locally (we are pulling in adal from CDN) and piping our telemetry provider into it, is there a way that I can turn this on w/o breaking minification?  I can define Logging as a var and make the bundler happy, but then it is disconnected from the Logging object in adal.

thanks,
~john

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the logging function to window.Logging:

```
window.Logging = {
    level: 3,
    log: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};
```

This basically what your code does. If you use "var" you are just defining a variable which doesn't overwrite window.Logging